# Why aren't constants included in the integration results?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

The question is to get the explicit formula for function $F$ for all $x$ s.t.

$F'(x) = x + |x-1|$

My solution ends with

$x^2 - x + c$, $for$ $x>=1$

$x + c$, $for$ $x<1$

However, the given solution gives the solution in the following form:

$x^2 - x + 1$, $for$ $x>=1$

$x$, $for$ $x<1$

Why isn't constant included in the second part of the solution?

And why the constant is 1 in the case of the first part of the solution?

Comment: Unless there are some kind of initial conditions given, your solution is correct: there should be a constant.

Comment: @AlexR., thanks. I thought this "for all $x$" is doing something weird that I don't know about.

Comment: Perhaps the problem asks to find \textbf{a} function F that satisfies those conditions, rather than the general form of any function F that satisfies those conditions?
Because if it just asks for some function to satisfy those conditions, their answer is acceptable. However if it does want the general form, then you are right in that it needs a constant of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your solution. The function you give equals $c$ at $1,$ while it has a limit of $1+c$ at $1$ from the left. You are correct that if we are looking for all solutions, a constant must appear somewhere. The given solution doesn't do that; it's just one correct specific solution – the one that equals $1$ at $1.$ To get all solutions, simply add a constant to this specific solution. Thus the general solution is $F(x) = x^2-x +c, x\ge 1,$ $F(x) = x-1 + c,x<1,$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Although this is true, this doesn't address the OP's concern. I would recommend leaving this as a comment, or editing it to answer the questions posed. I would also recommend using different constants for the $\geq 1$ and $<1$ cases because your current notation is confusing.

Comment: @StellaBiderman You are right, and I edited my answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Of course, the constants of integration must match up so that $F$ is continuous at $1$. It's worth pointing this out.